# Full wave rectifier above 0V

Tags: rectifier

I have a 1 kHz sine-wave signal with an amplitude of 5V (peak-to-peak), and a +2.5V offset.

I want to rectify the signal so that I only get the portion of the signal above 2.5V.

If the signal wasn't offset, this would be easy. I would just use a half-wave rectifier. But what do I do when my signal is offset above 0V?

I have a number of op-amps in my current project, so adding more wouldn't be a problem if that is what the solution requires.

Edit:

I have drawn a quick diagram of what I'm looking to do

[image]

Comment: Precision op amp rectifier with an offset.

Comment: I have the precision op amp rectifier working, but am having trouble implementing the offset portion of the circuit. Could you post what your thinking? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "so that I only get the portion of the signal above 2.5V"? What do you want to get if the signal is below 2.5V?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you draw a graph of the input signal and the desired output signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bring the signal down to be centered at GND by AC coupling and buffer it (OA0)
2. Do precision full wave rectification (OA1 and OA2)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdp2HZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the peak to peak value?  How about using a capacitor coupling and then a bridge rectifier.  If you want more precision use a capacitor to couple into a precision rectifier.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question asks for a Full wave but your description says a half wave. To keep things simple here is a half wave 'rectifier' that allows you to set some input voltage (in this case 2.5V) to rectify around.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZJLuR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>